how to consider second line as header while reading .csv file in Spark
I want to skip the first line and consider from second line, I used header start position as 2 and skip rows as 1, but it did not work as it is loading the second line also as data. can someone please suggest a working solution?
below is the sample data
Data:
Loan|||
Issue ID|Report Date|Pool ID|Loan ID
592029|31/03/2024|DTC1|65

Consider second line as header
and data from third line

What code did you try? Look's like you're using Spark, or a specific library to read the CSV?

If you can add a special character at the begining of this first row (or any other row you want to skip) then you can use comment option

Sets a single character used for skipping lines beginning with this character. By default, it is disabled.

#Loan|||
Issue ID|Report Date|Pool ID|Loan ID
#Another skipped line
592029|31/03/2024|DTC1|65

spark.read.option("comment", "#")
    .option("sep", "|")
    .option("header", true)
    .csv("<PATH>").show()

+--------+-----------+-------+-------+
|Issue ID|Report Date|Pool ID|Loan ID|
+--------+-----------+-------+-------+
|  592029| 31/03/2024|   DTC1|     65|
+--------+-----------+-------+-------+


One option is to use autoloader. See the link for the autoloader options.
Autoloader will pick up all the new files which have been loaded on the source folder and process.
You need to ensure that you set header to True and skipRows to 1. Something like
schema_path = "abfss://schema@<storage>.dfs.core.windows.net/...."
file_path = "abfss://file@<storage>.dfs.core.windows.net/..."
checkpoint_path = "abfss://checkpoint@<storage>.dfs.core.windows.net/..../"

df = (spark.readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", schema_path)
    .option("skipRows",1)
    .option("header",True)
    .option("delimiter","|")
    .load(file_path)
    .writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
    .trigger(availableNow=True)
    .toTable("test1"))

You can see from my test run, that the output is skipping the 1st row.

Please note that when storing the data to a delta table, you can't have spaces in the column names so you either need to change that at source(which is what I did) or change the column names before writing to a delta table.
